# cant open image from rc.local

Tags: raspbian, linux, ubuntu, archlinux

I would like to open image from rc.local. I am sure rc.local is getting called during boot as it execute/run test c++ code. I tried with various image viewer like gpicview , mirage. I can try with imagemagic but i don't think, image viewer is the problem. Something I am missing fundamental.

rc.local code:

```
cd /home/pi/test 
gpicview test.jpg
#mirage test.jpg #doesnt work so commented
exit (0)
```

How can resolve this issue? Any suggestion for further debugging?

Comment: Note : exit (0) is on next line some reason, copy past code didn't dispaly properly.

Comment: *GPicView - A Simple and Fast Image Viewer for X* - two things to ask. Is `X` running yet? would rc.local have access to it? If you want to run something when `X` starts, you need to use a different method (I'm sure there's plenty of information about how to start a program when `X` starts if you search)

Comment: thanks for comment, Let me have a read about 'X' starts sequence. How would i know , is X running?

Comment: You cannot start GUI stuff from `rc.local`, as explained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/difference-in-rc-local-and-lxde-autostart). Consider using LXDE autostart.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Looks like i found the answer. Let me try with LXDE autostart. I will update you tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can open gpicview image from LXDE autostart but doest run my script. I have script which picup image from various folder and display it. I am using @lxterminal -e "/home/pi/test/test.sh". Test.sh is executable (chmod +x). After reboot, i can see it open empty lxterminal window but doesn't run script.

Comment: test.sh script use exactly same gpicview to open image. test.sh script code: cd /home/pi/image    (next line) gpicview test.jpg

Comment: I have also tried with @/usr/bin/bash "/home/pi/test/test.sh" , doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be useful to someone:
Finally mange to get image open from LXDE autostart. 
I wrote script call test.sh :

```bash
cd /home/pi/test
gpicview test.jpg
```

Next Step :This script to be executable with
`chmod +x test.sh`

Then modified LXDE autostart script:

```
@/home/pi/test/test.sh
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
```

Reboot device.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.